# What's up with this Angular's documentation dumb statement about parentheses?

Tags: angular

While reading about Angular [Injectable services](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4), I came across this statement:

> Don't forget the parentheses. Omitting them leads to an error that's difficult to diagnose.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
}
```

- Really?
- What error?
- Why is it difficult to diagnose?
- In what scenarios will it be difficult to diagnose?
- Are all Editors equal when it comes to diagnosing that error?
- Are parentheses required just to avoid that mysterious error?

Enough questions.

**Update**:

> Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression. Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

Even though that is the error I get, but is that really the so called "difficult" error to diagnose?

Comment: There is some discussion about this on GitHub in the Typescript issues section: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3246

Comment: This was suggested before and turned down. According to the user with the first comment after the proposal (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13173), there is a difference between decorators and decorator factories, the latter of which require parenthesis.

Comment: Considering that the "decorators" are functions that take the next thing close to them as parameter, it makes sense that they need to be invoked by means of (). Most iikely at the time that this point was written, ts wasnt smart enough to complain about the missing (). As the current versions of angular/visual studio code, the compiler complains if the () arent there

Answer (score 4):

Taken from: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13173, referring to the necessity of the parentheses following a Component declaration. I imagine this works similarly for the Injectable decorator.

> The Component function in your example is not a decorator at all it is
>   a decorator factory. That is to say it is simply a function which you
>   call, perhaps passing an argument, which returns the decorator that is
>   applied to the target by the @ syntax.